# Finding matching submatrices inside a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 100x200 2D array expressed as a numpy array consisting of black (0) and white (255) cells. It is a bitmap file. I then have 2D shapes (it's easiest to think of them as letters) that are also 2D black and white cells.

I know I can naively iterate through the matrix but this is going to be a 'hot' portion of my code so speed is an concern. Is there a fast way to perform this in numpy/scipy?

I looked briefly at Scipy's correlate function. I am not interested in 'fuzzy matches', only exact matches. I also looked at some academic papers but they are above my head.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *can* use correlate. You'll need to set your black values to -1 and your white values to 1 (or vice-versa) so that you know the value of the peak of the correlation, and that it only occurs with the correct letter.

The following code does what I think you want.

```
import numpy
from scipy import signal

# Set up the inputs
a = numpy.random.randn(100, 200)
a[a<0] = 0
a[a>0] = 255

b = numpy.random.randn(20, 20)
b[b<0] = 0
b[b>0] = 255

# put b somewhere in a
a[37:37+b.shape[0], 84:84+b.shape[1]] = b

# Now the actual solution...

# Set the black values to -1
a[a==0] = -1
b[b==0] = -1

# and the white values to 1
a[a==255] = 1
b[b==255] = 1

max_peak = numpy.prod(b.shape)

# c will contain max_peak where the overlap is perfect
c = signal.correlate(a, b, 'valid')

overlaps = numpy.where(c == max_peak)

print overlaps
```

This outputs `(array([37]), array([84]))`, the locations of the offsets set in the code.

You will likely find that if your letter size multiplied by your big array size is bigger than roughly Nlog(N), where N is corresponding size of the big array in which you're searching (for each dimension), then you will probably get a speed up by using an fft based algorithm like `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` (bearing in mind that you'll need to flip each axis of one of the datasets if you're using a convolution rather than a correlation - `flipud` and `fliplr`). The only modification would be to assigning c:

```
c = signal.fftconvolve(a, numpy.fliplr(numpy.flipud(b)), 'valid')
```

Comparing the timings on the sizes above:

```
In [5]: timeit c = signal.fftconvolve(a, numpy.fliplr(numpy.flipud(b)), 'valid')
100 loops, best of 3: 6.78 ms per loop

In [6]: timeit c = signal.correlate(a, b, 'valid')
10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wow, great answer (timings even)! I've got some tests to run.

Comment: Something just occurred to me, you can have "don't care" regions of your submatrix by setting the value to 0. This means those values will have no impact on the cross-correlation. The `max_peak` value could then be found as `max_peak = b[b!=0].size` (this would work whether or not you have 0 values).

Comment: So I've spent the afternoon editing my code and have got it working! Let's say 2 occurrences were found of a 2x3 shape at (array([0, 6]), array([1, 7])) meaning the upper left corners are [0, 1] and [6, 7]. What I want to do is to be able to index all 2x3 cells of the shape and assign them 0 so on the next shape we're looking for we won't check that portion of the image (per your comment above). How can I use the return value of correlate/fftconvolve to index the 2d shape without using loops? Sort of a list-of-location slice.

Comment: Is that what you want to do? Setting to zero is equivalent to setting a don't care, which means it will more likely be picked up. It's also difficult to set the max_peak if you're setting zeros in the main search array. Unless your sub array contains another sub array, you'll have no problem, and then the best way is to carefully set your search order, and possibly pollute the data (by flipping a 1 to a -1 or vice versa) to break the searching for future shapes. Flipping a single value at the offset should be enough to enforce this.

Comment: Note that `flipud(fliplr(x))` is a matlabism --- you can write `x[::-1, ::-1]` instead.

Comment: @pv. flipud and fliplr have the advantage of being very clear about what they're doing. I'd argue opaque index schemes are less so, despite their _marginal_ speed increase.

Comment: @HenryGomersall: I'd argue the indexing scheme is in this case not obscure at all, but rather a well-known Python idiom.

Comment: @pv. fair enough, we can all use what we prefer. Thanks for the addition.

Comment: @HenryGomersall I am sorting my list of shapes by width as it is variable (height is fixed) then searching widest to smallest shape. The issue is that wider shapes can include smaller shapes so by going largest to smallest and somehow 'masking off' used areas I can avoid seeing those smaller shapes in the larger shapes. So far it's seeming to work by using zeros, but am missing a few instances of shapes. It could very well be other bugs though - I'm still working through it.

Comment: @DaveO If you set values in the main array to zero, then those points aren't going to contribute to the main correlation, so the output from the correlation will be some value which is not easy to know _a priori_, so without lots of extra code, you're going to miss some. The way I would do it would be to check that the indices of the small submatrices don't lie inside the big ones, which could be done very fast as a simple comparison (since you know the offsets and the sizes).

Comment: Switching the 'mask' to 1 instead of 0, and using correlate instead of fftconvolve got them all! Not sure why fftconvolve missed some, but it's working great. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why is my overlaps giving me an output of (array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))

Comment: What I see is that if I run 3 to 4 times or may be ten times, I get the correct result. But after that I do not. I have put it inside a function and have to run recursively till I get a position. Can anybody explain?

Comment: @tor9ado try asking a new question

Answer (score 9):

Here is a method you may be able to use, or adapt, depending upon the details of your requirements. It uses [`ndimage.label` and `ndimage.find_objects`:](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html)

1. label the image using `ndimage.label` this finds all blobs in the array and labels them to integers.
2. Get the slices of these blobs using `ndimage.find_objects`
3. Then use set intersection to see if the `found blobs` correspond with your `wanted blobs`

Code for `1.` and `2.`:

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#flatten to ensure greyscale.
im = scipy.misc.imread('letters.png',flatten=1)
objects, number_of_objects = ndimage.label(im)
letters = ndimage.find_objects(objects)

#to save the images for illustrative purposes only:
plt.imsave('ob.png',objects)
for i,j in enumerate(letters):
    plt.imsave('ob'+str(i)+'.png',objects[j])
```

example input:

[image]

labelled:

[image]

isolated blobs to test against:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Amazing! This is nearly what I'm trying to do. I'll have to try both answers and see what works best. Thanks for taking the time to post this!