# counting 2*2 squares in n*n binary matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got an n*n binary matrix (only 1 and 0), how can I go about counting 2*2 squares (squares are made by 1)

for example `A=[[1,1],[1,1]]` is considered to make one 2*2 square. or

```
A = [[1, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

is considered to make four 2*2 squares.
here's my code for this , but I just don't know why it doesn't work.

```
A = [[1, 1, 0, 1] , [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
result=[]
for x in range(len(A)-1):
    for y in range(len(A)-1):
        if A[x][y]==1:
            if A[x+1][y]==1:
                if A[x][y+1]==1 or A[x][y-1]==1 and A[x+1][y] or A[x+1][y-1]==1:
                    result.append(1)
            if A[x-1][y]==1:
                if A[x][y+1]==1 or A[x][y-1]==1 and A[x-1][y] or A[x-1][y-1]==1:
                    result.append(1)        
print(len(result))
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Generate indices for width - 1 by height - 1; `itertools.product()` can do this for us.
- Test 4 coordinates for each generated index using `all()` to only test as many as needed to disprove a square exists.
- Use `sum()` with a generator to count the number of squares found; faster than manually counting with a list or a counter.

Together with lambda to test for squares, this then becomes:

```
from itertools import product

def count_squares(A):
    width, height = len(A[0]), len(A)
    indices = product(range(width - 1), range(height - 1))
    is_square = lambda x, y: all(A[a][b] == 1 for a, b in product((x, x + 1), (y, y + 1)))
    return sum(1 for x, y in indices if is_square(x, y))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> count_squares([[1,1],[1,1]])
>>> def count_squares(A):
...     width, height = len(A[0]), len(A)
...     indices = product(range(width - 1), range(height - 1))
...     is_square = lambda x, y: all(A[a][b] == 1 for a, b in product((x, x + 1), (y, y + 1)))
...     return sum(1 for x, y in indices if is_square(x, y))
... 
>>> count_squares([[1,1],[1,1]])
1
>>> count_squares([[1, 1, 0, 1] , [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1]])
4
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the column count use len(A[x]) so

```
for y in range(len(A)-1)
```

becomes

```
for y in range(len(A[x])-1)
```

Change

```
if A[x][y]==1:
        if A[x+1][y]==1:
            if A[x][y+1]==1 or A[x][y-1]==1 and A[x+1][y] or A[x+1][y-1]==1:
                result.append(1)
        if A[x-1][y]==1:
            if A[x][y+1]==1 or A[x][y-1]==1 and A[x-1][y] or A[x-1][y-1]==1:
                result.append(1)
```

To

```
        if A[x][y]==1 and A[x+1][y]==1 and a[x+1][y+1]==1 and a[x][y+1]:
             result.append(1)
```

Unless you want to count squares multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`scipy.signal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) there is a simple solution that finds the correlation between your target and the input. This is nice since it generalizes to "almost matches" and arbitrary shapes!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

A = np.array([[1,1,0,1] ,[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1]],dtype=int)
b = np.ones((2,2),dtype=int)

c   = signal.correlate(A, b, 'valid')
idx = np.where(c==4)
count = sum(idx[0])

print count
```

This gives `4` as expected. If you find this interesting, there is a (longer) answer that uses this same idea:

[Finding matching submatrices inside a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11079590/249341)

Answer (score 0):

I multipliply the values of every 2*2-submatrix and sum up:

```
A = [[1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1]]

sum( A[x][y]*A[x+1][y]*A[x][y+1]*A[x+1][y+1] 
         for y in range(len(A)-1)
         for x in range(len(A[y])-1)
)


Out[79]: 4
```